# IBM BlueMix-404 Error

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, watson-iot

I am new to Bluemix and running into trouble when attempting to "View App" while it is running. This is using the Watson IoT Starter boilerplate. Git is connected.

I have deleted and recreated that application multiple times but continue to encounter the same issue.

```
"404 Not Found: Requested route ('courserastartapp.mybluemix.net') does not exist."
```

Is anyone else having the problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you still have a problem here? I pointed my browser to courserastartapp.mybluemix.net and the app is running.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the boilerplate, especially the npm part, takes a while to complete and make the route viewable. Are you restarting without giving it enough time to complete the process?  Try waiting about 5 minutes after deploy to view the route.  If it still does not work then check the deployment logs and let us know what errors you see.

Edited to add: we hope to have a fix in place soon